# Ledger Nano not signing

Tags: baking-node

I am getting this error message....can someone provide some advice?  Found no ledger corresponding to ledger://Xxxx-insect-xxxxxxx-animal/ed25519/0'/0' with filter "App = Baking".

Comment: Can you share some more details about what you are trying? Some details that would help: What network are you on - mainnet? What version of the app are you using? Confirming you are using the Baking App? What are you trying to do/sign?

Thanks!

Comment: - on the mainnet

Comment: -on mainnet. Using most recent baking app. I figure Ed our the issue. I updated MacOS to Catalina. However, i did not shut down the node properly. I had to unplug Ledger Nano and restart Baking App. All is good now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome! Happy to hear it. Since you've solved your issue, I recommend marking it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: See above comments..I was able resolve the issue.

Comment: please post your answer as an actual answer so that people can follow more closely this resolution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

-on mainnet. Using most recent baking app. I figure Ed our the issue. I updated MacOS to Catalina. However, i did not shut down the node properly. I had to unplug Ledger Nano and restart Baking App. All is good now. Thanks for the help! – Adi_daz Jul 30 at 22:56    Delete